# All frameworks and dylibs for bitcode must be generated from Xcode Archive or Install build file

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, testflight, bitcode

I'm having troubles when Archiving my React Native iOS app.

When I run the app on simulator or my iPhone everything works fine. But when I try to archive my app to publish it on TestFlight the archive process finishes up with this error:

ld: **bitcode bundle could not be generated because** `'/Users/Chavez/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-bspgkawckaqxrhcpajufutlpmuok/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/MyApp/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/Payments.framework/Payments'` **was built without full bitcode. All frameworks and dylibs for bitcode must be generated from Xcode Archive or Install build file** `'/Users/Chavez/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-bspgkawckaqxrhcpajufutlpmuok/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/MyApp/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/Payments.framework/Payments'` **for architecture arm64**

In my project I have integrated:

1. Payments.xcframework (no bitcode ?)
2. RLTMXProfiling.xcframework (bitcode)
3. RLTMXProfilingConnections.xcframework (bitcode)

May this error be caused because **Payments.xcframework** has no bitcode enabled? 
All the framework must be bitcode enabled?
Is there any way to know if **Payments.xcframework** has bitcode enabled?

I've only seen `otool` comand to check it, but I couldn't use it on XCFramework.
I also tried everything in this guide:
[Static Libraries, Frameworks, and Bitcode](https://medium.com/@heitorburger/static-libraries-frameworks-and-bitcode-6d8f784478a9) but still no luck.

Anyone could give any more ideas? I will be grateful.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way I could archive my app was setting `Enable bitcode` to `No` in both **Project** and **Target** in the *Build Settings* tab. But still... couldn't find a way to archive with bitcode enabled